# OpenNI SDK2, can't find Kinect device (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: kinect, openni, ubuntu-13.04

I downloaded OpenNI SDK2 sources x64, compiled and tried to run Samples, but wasnt successful.

```
  100 INFO       New log started on 2013-10-27 00:03:47
  130 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
  166 VERBOSE    No override device in configuration file
  182 VERBOSE    Configuration has been read from './OpenNI.ini'
  190 VERBOSE    OpenNI 2.2.0 (Build 32)-Linux-x86 (Oct 26 2013 21:13:04)
  197 VERBOSE    Using './OpenNI2/Drivers' as driver path
  208 VERBOSE    Looking for drivers in drivers repository './OpenNI2/Drivers'
  933 INFO       New log started on 2013-10-27 00:03:47
  950 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
  966 VERBOSE    Initializing USB...
 1074 INFO       USB is initialized.
 4274 INFO       New log started on 2013-10-27 00:03:47
 4292 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
 4304 VERBOSE    Initializing USB...
 4366 INFO       USB is initialized.

15321 VERBOSE    Trying to open device by URI '(NULL)'
15367 ERROR      Can't open default device - none found
Couldn't open device
DeviceOpen using default: no devices found
```

lsusb gets this

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:b002 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:00f0 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0603 LighTuning Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

I also tried some **libfreenect** examples with kinect a it worked without any problem.

I add some line to SimpleRead main.cpp file

```
Array<DeviceInfo> dev_info;
OpenNI::enumerateDevices(&dev_info);
printf("Number of devices %d \n",dev_info.getSize());
```

which writes out 0.

Output of 
`lsmod | grep gspca_kinect`  is void

What could be possibly wrong?

I'm on Ubuntu 64bit v13.04, Kinect is "Kinect for Xbox", using USB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered by the OP in an edit, see [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> According to [OpenNI forum topic](http://community.openni.org/openni/topics/about_kinect_support_on_mac_linux)
>
> new OpenNI SDK2 doesnt support Kinect device. Anyway, there is a [link](https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver) to OpenKinect drivers "hacked" to work with OpenNI SDK2

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this answer because @Brian Tompsett's link is broken. There is an easy workaround to this while compiling libfreenect: just ensure you turn on the flag `-DBUILD_OPENNI2_DRIVER=ON` when calling `cmake` during `libfreenect's` build.

After installing, head over to

`/home/$(whoami)/path/to/libfreenect/build/lib/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver`

and copy `libFreenectDriver.so*` to your downloaded OpenNI2 Bin directory, i.e.: `/path/to/OpenNI2/Bin/x64-Release/`

Check if your installation is okay by testing the precompiled `NiViewer`. Depending on the rules you configured in your udev folder, you might need to run `NiViewer` with root.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

@Calorified 's answer worked for me.

In addition, make sure to update the `OpenNI.ini` file, e.g. to run the OpenNI sample apps in `OpenNI2/Samples/Bin` or the NiTE sample apps in `/path/to/NiTE*/Samples/Bin`.

For example, I was using the 32-bit OpenNI version 2.2:

1. I copied the `libFreenectDriver.so*` to `/path/to/OpenNI2/Tools` (there is no `bin/x64-release` folder in this OpenNI version).
2. In `OpenNI2/Samples/Bin`, edit the file `OpenNI.ini`
3. Under the `[Drivers]` section, at the end of the file, add the line: `Repository=/path/to/OpenNI2/Tools` (where you put the `libFreenectDriver.so` file). Below is my edited OpenNI.ini file. I used a relative path, but an absolute path will also work.

   ```
   #/path/to/OpenNI2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI.ini
   [Log]
   ; 0 - Verbose; 1 - Info; 2 - Warning; 3 - Error. Default - None
   Verbosity=3
   LogToConsole=0
   LogToFile=0

   [Device]
   ;Override=""

   [Drivers]
   ; Location of the drivers specified by a relative path based on  OpenNI's shared library or an absolute path.
   ; Path separator "/" can be used to be portable for any platforms.
   ; Default - OpenNI2/Drivers
   Repository=../../Tools
   ```

You'll have to do the same thing for the NiTE samples. The samples should run now.

Without updating the `OpenNI.ini` I always get the error `DeviceOpen using default: no devices found`

*ps. libfreenect installation will put the `libFreenectDriver.so` in `/usr/local/lib/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/`